# Google login api issue with redirect

Tags: php, api, google-api

I've set up the google login api and when google tries to redirect to my website after login but it has a strange issue with the GET request.

The redirect url is:

> redirect.php?code=4%2F0ARtbsJp9eHh60OapNBiwOC3xzpGossbHO1k3ZvOr2DMwttkgeFfaWVafW8cNCDSgAn3ZaA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent

The problem is the GET request seems to not function after `.profile` and it just shows my home page again. When I remove `.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent` , the url works correctly but GET request is incomplete.

Can it be because of some settings in `Cloudflare`?

I'm trying to receive the complete GET['code'] result which is:

> 4%2F0ARtbsJp9eHh60OapNBiwOC3xzpGossbHO1k3ZvOr2DMwttkgeFfaWVafW8cNCDSgAn3ZaA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent

Comment: should there be spaces in the url decoded strings?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example].  Authorization code is the second step you need to exchange that for an access token and refresh token.